# Word - Use restricted editing with track changes enabled

Tags: vba, ms-word

In one of my word documents it's necessary to restrict editing on some parts of the text.

If I enable the "restricted editing  mode", the "track changes" feature is being disabled ("greyed out").

Is there a way to use both the "restricted editing" and the "track changes" feature?

It'd be no problem if I had to use a macro for that, I'm quite familiar with VBA.

---

This is a screenshot of the problem :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to combine the two functionalities. If any document protection is in-force then tracking changes is not available.

About the only way you could do it would be to provide the non-editable text as graphic objects. They'd be delete-able, but you could use code to check whether everything is present and not allow the document to be saved/printed if anything is missing.

The other possibility that occurs to me would be to remove protection at some point and compare the version the user was editing with a saved version of the original (CompareDocuments), then re-instate protection.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Your last idea is brilliant, I'm gonna try that out! Thanks for your help.